# Python - generate derangements of string.ascii_lowercase

Tags: python, cryptography, brute-force, encryption

I have found some algorithms online to generate derangements in Python but they're all exponential in complexity and as a result I can't get them to converge with a set of 26 elements (the alphabet)!

So I'm trying to find a way to improve the following code (source [here](http://www.voofie.com/content/57/a-procedure-to-list-all-derangements-of-a-multiset/)):

```
def derangement(vs):
    l = [None for x in vs]
    sol = set()
    sol.add(tuple(l))
    for v in vs:
        sol1 = set()
        for s in sol:
            for (i, v1) in enumerate(s):
                if not v1 and v != vs[i]:
                    s1 = list(s)
                    s1[i] = v
                    sol1.add(tuple(s1))
        sol = sol1
    return list(sol)
```

If anyone is curious this is for a bruteforce substitution cipher solver. I'm trying to see how long it takes to bruteforce a cipher!

Comment: The number of permutations grows exponentially (or, more precisely, factorially).  Every algorithm generating all permutations of n objects is Ω(n!).

Comment: have you checked `itertools` module?

Comment: Sven, `itertools.permutations` creates the list of all permutations almost instantly.

Comment: JBernardo I have, it does not give anything for derangements. Just permutations. That is not valid for Substitution ciphers.

Comment: @user: `itertools.permutations()` returns a lazy iterator.  Try `list(itertools.permutations(string.lowercase))`.

Comment: yeah but you can make a derangement out of `permutations` with a single line of code

Comment: Sven, you might have assumed that my environment would have protected me but that actually crashed my computer.

Comment: @user: Really sorry.  It didn't crash mine (I also tried) and it definitely shouldn't crash *any* computer.

Comment: It gobbled up all my memory and CPU and I wasn't even able to ctrl-alt-del, so I wouldn't say "any" computer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As permutation algorithms are Ω(n!) nothing will make your code converge. This may be faster, but that means nothing for things of that complexity:

```
import itertools
def derangement(x):
    p = itertools.permutations(x)
    return (i for i in p if not any(i[k] == x[k] for k in range(len(x))))
```

It's a lazy iterator. If you need all values (I doubt you need) just `list()` it

Comment: I did not know it was a lazy iterator so thanks for the heads up and the optimization. I guess with a general purpose computer bruteforcing a substitution cipher is a shot in the dark!

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, it depends on the cypher you're using. If you're using a Caesar cypher which I'm sure you aren't, you only have to try all 26! Permutations and then find the one*('s) with real words but I'm pretty sure you mean for a vigenere cypher in which case you take all of the first set of permutations and you lay those in rows of a similar faction and find those permutations and then cross check for dictionary words and then you'd probably get a very long list of possible messages and you'd have to sort through those for one that made sense.

Comment: those are shift ciphers, the substitution cipher is a cipher where the key is a mapping of the alphabet to a permutation of the alphabet, i.e. A = C, B = Q, C = T ...

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about how vast the number of derangement of 26 items is: using SymPy one can calculate the number of derangements of 26 items to be the subfactorial of 26 (!26)

```
>>> subfactorial(26)
148362637348470135821287825
>>> round(log(_,2))
87
```

So there are about `2^87` derangements of the alphabet that are possible. There are some routines [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6662) for computing random derangements and a method of generating successive derangements without storing them all in memory as the routine cited in the intitial question above.